# How to create a multiview application in xcode 4 using UINavigation Controller without a TableView?

Tags: xcode4, tableview, navigationcontroller

I'm new to iPhone development. I would like to understand how to create a multiview application without TableView. The brief description of the program is: it includes three views, each one has a button. When user taps button it takes him to the next screen going in a circle. 1-2.2-3.3-1.

Two things are most important:

1. How to get rid of TableView and use NavigationController without it?
2. How to get back from the third view to the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using UINavigationController with UIView's it is pretty easy.  Have a view or button on view 1, that intercepts the touch action.

Shows binding a touch action to the button on your view 1

```
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This shows how the method pushes a new controller to the navigation.  You can do this on view 2 to take you to view 3 as well.

```
-(void)button2Pressed:(id)sender {
   UIView view2 = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
}
```

Finally, if you want to get back to view 1

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The best way to learn about the various options is to check out the documentation  [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).